# Rand() Returning Same Value With Every Function Call

Tags: c++

Whenever I call a specific method in my class file, I return a random value, but it then proceeds to return the same value each time that method is called again.

For example

```
int CommuterTrain::getRandNumber(int maximumValue)
{
    srand(unsigned(time(NULL)));

    int maximum = maximumValue;
    return rand()%maximum+1;
}

void CommuterTrain::loadRiders()
{
    int passengers = getRandNumber(350);
    currentRiders += passengers;
    if (currentRiders > maxCapacity) {
        cout << "The train has reached capacity! \nSome people were left at the station."
                 << endl;
        currentRiders = maxCapacity;
    }
    else {  
        cout<<passengers<<" pax have entered the vessel"<<endl;
    }
}
```

Let's say the generator produces a number of 215 pax. When I call the method again, it doesn't randomize again and I wind up with 215 every time.

Is the issue in the generator, or is it in the following method?

Comment: Only seed the generator once

Comment: Why are you seeding `rand` every time? You should do that once on program start-up.

Comment: Soooooooooooooooo many duplicates...

Comment: Stop it! You're not Johnny Appleseed or a porn star!

Comment: I think this wins the award for most re-asked question.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because its clearly a duplicate. This "I'm seeding the PRNG every time I use it" question is duplicated dozens of times along SO

Comment: @Manu343726 Specify the right duplicate link, and I'll follow to close vote (been here, seen that ...). May be one should make this a canonical (@lightness-races-in-orbit Have an advice?).

Answer (score 1):

You keep reseeding it. With the same seed (assuming you have a computer that is newer than 1920 and can therefore execute your code in under a second<sup>†</sup>). Don't do that.

It means you keep regenerating *and restarting* the same pseudo-random sequence over and over again. Consequently, you keep pulling out the same first value in that sequence with each call to `rand()`.

**Seed only *once* in your program.**

You could put the `srand` call in `main`, for example.

<sup><sup>†</sup> It could take around a second provided you began execution just as a new second began. Integer logic and all that. Whatever.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is, that you're seeding the random engine with every call to your function:

```
int CommuterTrain::getRandNumber(int maximumValue)
{
    srand(unsigned(time(NULL))); // <<< This line causes your problems

    int maximum = maximumValue;
    return rand()%maximum+1;
}
```

The current `time()` result is unlikely to change significantly in between calls to the `getRandNumber()` function.

You should call `srand(time(NULL))` once **outside** your function instead (e.g. in your `CommuterTrain` class constructor, or even better from `main()` only).